# Integrate Glassfish server with eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to integrate glassfish3 with eclipse kepler.
I have downloaded and installed glassfish server. But the problem is with server adapters in eclipse. While downloading additional server adapters in eclipse, it doesn't show glassfish server adapters.
Am I doing something wrong or is there any other work-around.
Please suggest, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Restart Eclipse and try again. I just tested this on a new Kepler SR2 Java EE kit. GlassFish Tools does come up in the dialog and I was able to install. Perhaps there was a network glitch during discovery?

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment suggested this may be some kind of network glitch and you should try again.

Another option is to install the **GlassFish Tools for Eclipse Kepler** via the **Eclipse Marketplace**.

Click `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace` and search for glassfish. Install and restart and you should be able to add your server instance in the `Servers` tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem, then I found there is a search option too. this worked for me and got glassfish tool as search result.